# Reported Answer Time and Deleting Answers

Tags: discussion, answers, deleted-answers

Having been on this site for a few months now, I've noticed that the first-to-answer answer tends to get the most upvotes; all other things being approximately equal.

In order to maximise your rate of reputation increase, one could do the following (1) answer a question poorly but promptly, (2) delete the answer (which renders it invulnerable to downvoting), (3) edit the answer off-line, (4) undelete it and commit your edits.

You will then have an excellent answer that will appear first in a chronological output.

Personally I think this is unfair.

**I suggest that the 'answer time' clock is reset on an undelete.**

Comments please?

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9731/fastest-gun-in-the-west-problem

Answer (score 6):

#### Answer then delete is not an effective rep strategy

The fact that early answers get the most votes isn't because they are chronologically first, its because they are exposed to early upvotes, something which is unavailable if you post then delete.

Often people order by votes, as such getting the first few upvotes puts you higher up the list and so you are more visible to receive more upvotes; visibility is key, if you've deleted your answer it is invisible. The majority of the time answer time is not considered at all except with identical answers where answer time is used to establish which was (probably) copied from the other.

In this context the most effective way to generate rep is to promptly answer a "good enough" answer and then edit it to improve it. It has been [discussed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9731/fastest-gun-in-the-west-problem) and agreed that we in no way want to discourage the "good enough" fast answers.

#### Resetting answer time clock

At present the information is correct, the fact that it was deleted and undeleted is recorded in the edit history (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/1642314/revisions) for an example) and the true time that it was posted is recorded. Your suggestion is to replace full and correct information with something that is untrue.